# Convert to number in excel using vb

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

In my code i am creating an excel but some cells must be numbers.

My code :

```
 oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
 oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
 oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Test"
 array1(i, 1) = 0
 oSheet.Range("B1").NumberFormat = "0.00"
 oSheet.Range("A2").Resize(i, 1).Value = array1
 oBook.SaveAs("C:\New folder\excel\" & datenw & ".xlsx")
 oBook.Close(True)
 oExcel.Quit()
```

Now i received this :

[image: image1]

But i would like to received this :

[image: image2]

Comment: What is the nature of the error Excel is flagging to you?

Comment: Try `CDbl(Range("xx").Value)`.

Comment: Your code inserts the array into column A but you are formatting column B and your results image does NOT show column A. Also your code does not show how Array was created so we don't know if it contains numbers or strings.

Comment: the array is created like : Dim array1(lines, 12) As String